# Tracing using Correlation-ID/etc when one service A makes multiple calls to service B

Tags: distributed-transactions, distributed-tracing

If a user calls service A, and service A then calls service B, tracing is simple using the correlation ID.

Now if service A calls service B multiple times, the same correlationID gets used for each of those calls, which makes tracing slightly tricky.

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

This task can be solved by adding some context information to your traces.
Whole trace should have a single ID, let's name it **TraceID**. Is should be generated once, when the first request started execution, and added to trace context to be propagated to all child requests in a chain. Each subsequent call in a distributed request should have additional identifier, let's name it **SpanID** (it is also known as ActivityID is some systems). SpanID should be generated by each service individually for each request or inbound message. And finally, the parent SpanID simply named as **ParentID** should be stored in context to keep track of a parent request. The combination of a TraceID and ParentID can uniquely identify the parent request globally, regardless of what process it executed in.
[image]

Here is a W3C standard describing HTTP headers and value format of distributed trace context: https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/.
In accordance to specification, trace header named `traceparent` is composed by 4 fields: `version` - `traceid` - `parentid/spanid` - `traceflags`.

For example:
`00-0af7651916cd43dd8448eb211c80319c-b7ad6b7169203331-00`

W3C trace context spec has ready to use implementations for commonly used languages, such as Java, .NET, Python and others.